# cron job dos not work with amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

cron job dos not work with amazon elastic beanstalk
i have created a cronjob.config inside a .ebextensions like this

```
files:
"/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
\* \* \* \* \* root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/artisan schedule:run 1\>\> /dev/null 2\>&1

commands:
remove_old_cron:
command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/\*.bak"
```

and it did not work
thanks .

Comment: Did you check any logs to try to debug that? Any errors?

Comment: there are no erros